# How do I install Chromium on F17?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, package-management, yum, chrome

I just installed the Beefy Miracle on my box, but essentially being the first time I've used Linux I'm not sure how to perform even some of the most basic tasks.

I thought I would try to install Chromium as a starting exercise. I tried:

```
sudo yum install chromium
```

but the package doesn't exist. How does this work on Linux? I could easily `sudo yum install Git`, but I can't for Chromium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome is not opensource...

If you want to install Chromium on F17 you should use this repo :

```
http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/spot/chromium-stable/
```

Here's a full tuto : https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Chromium

Ps : Why Chromium Isn't in Fedora : http://ostatic.com/blog/making-projects-easier-to-package-why-chromium-isnt-in-fedora

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

For Chromium you [can use](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Chromium) the [chromium-stable](http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/spot/chromium-stable/) repo.

For Google Chrome, go to http://www.google.com/chrome and download the RPM for Fedora. If I remember correctly, it will add Google's repository for automatic updates.